# Select specific row and column by indexing on dataframe directly

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
d = {'col1': [33,34,35], 'col2': [5,6,8], 'col3': [7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df[['col1','col3']].head()
```

With the code above, I can select `col1` and `col3`, but if I wish to select only row 1 and row 3 (with value `[33,35]`, and `[7,9]`) without the usage of any function (e.g., `loc`, `iloc`, `at`, `iat` etc.) - purely using indexing on dataframe e.g., `df[..,..]`, is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: But why not use `.iloc`/`.loc`? The docs specifically state, "The most robust and consistent way of slicing ranges along arbitrary axes is described in the Selection by Position section detailing the .iloc method. "

Comment: @ALollz just to know the possibility without that

Comment: Typically it's chained indexing, which is discouraged and will frequently lead to SetWithCopy warnings.

Comment: why not using the way they recommended ?

Comment: Whether you find it useful or not, I think the proper way to index in this case of discontinuous integer indices that may be single elements or ranges, across multiple columns is `df.loc[np.r_[0,2], ['col1', 'col3']]` using the `numpy.r_` method to specify all of your indices

Answer (score 2):

Use indexing, index second element by `1`, use `1` since indexing in python starts with `0`:

```
print(df['col1'][1])
```

**Update** get columns transpose the data-frame, then get columns `0` and `2`, since transposed, then transpose back:

```
print(df[['col1','col3']].T[[0,2]].T)
```

Or:

```
print(df[df.index.isin([0,2])][['col1','col3']])
```

Comment: But say if I want to select more than 1 column with more than 1 row?

Comment: @william007 Edited mine

Comment: So function like `iloc` must be used in this case?

Comment: @william007 Now?

Comment: Looks interesting but more complicated, I was originally hope to make it simpler, and I am thinking something like specifying rows and columns in the indexer like df[<row>,  <col>], this does not work out am I right?

Comment: Thanks for all the effort, this looks interesting. If we can get rid of all used functions it would be even better, but I doubt that. Upvoted it :)

Comment: @william007 `index` is not a function, it's an attribute.

Comment: All this is chained indexing is *really* not recommended when you are learning Pandas. You should use `loc` / `iloc`. Can you explain how `df.__getitem__` (which is what you are using each time you use `[]`) decides what to do each time? I certainly can't.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, there are several approaches to this. Two points to consider are: what makes sense from a readability/Pythonic/idiomatic perspective and what makes sense from a performance perspective. My possible solutions do not meet the OP's full specification to avoid functions, but I will offer them for consideration and for comparison.

Let's look at three approaches and consider them from both perspectives.

In this case, to help us more clearly see some of the performance aspects by timing the code execution, we increased the size of the DataFrame, by repeating the stored values 100,000 times.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[32, 33, 34] * 100000,
                   'col2':[1, 2, 3] * 100000,
                   'col3':[1, 2, 3] * 100000,
                  })
```

**APPROACH 1**

This approach uses the process outlined by @U9-Forward, i.e. index by columns, transpose the rows and columns so that you can then index the desired rows and transpose the DataFrame back to the original orientation.

Using `%timeit` in Jupyter, we see how long this approach takes to process:

```
[1]: %timeit df[['col1', 'col3']].T[[0, 2]].T
     3.02 ms ± 16.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**APPROACH 2**

This approach creates a mask based on a list of desired rows and the index and filters the DataFrame based on that mask, and then selects for just the desired columns. This has some similarity to @jpp's approach, but doesn't use `.loc`.

Similarly, using `%timeit`... we see that this approach takes half as long as Approach 1.

```
[2]: %timeit df[df.index.isin([0, 2])][['col1', 'col3']]
     1.61 ms ± 31.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**APPROACH 3**

A third approach uses the `.take()` method to select specific rows from the DataFrame and then indexes for the desired columns.

Again, using `%timeit`, we see that this approach is **three times faster** than approach 2, and **six times faster** than approach 1.

```
[1]: %timeit df.take([0, 2])[['col1','col3']]
     507 µs ± 5.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

It is also arguable that this approach is potentially easier to read than the first two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Would this satisfy what you are looking for? :

```
df[['col1','col3']][::2]
```

Here I took advantage of the fact that the row indexes you asked (0 and 2) can be expressed as a slice. For an arbitrary set of row indexes, though, it might not be possible to make it as simple

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

You are looking to combine **integer positional** indexing with **label-based** indexing. This is often cumbersome, but here you can use the fact `iloc` supports integer positional *and* Boolean array indexing:

```
d = {'col1': [33,34,35], 'col2': [5,6,8], 'col3': [7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

res = df.iloc[[0, 2], df.columns.isin(['col1', 'col3'])]

print(res)

   col1  col3
0    33     7
2    35     9
```

Indexing in Python begins with `0`, so the first and third rows are represented by `[0, 2]`.

An alternative is to use `loc` with Boolean indexing for rows:

```
res = df.loc[df.index.isin([0, 2]), ['col1', 'col3']]
```

Since *usually* row count exceeds column count, and also because integer positional indexing is naturally more efficient than label-based, you may prefer `iloc` over `loc`.